# Zeta function in complex analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, self-learning

Show that $$\frac{\zeta'(z)}{\zeta(z)}=-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{f(z)}{n^z}$$ for $\Re z\gt 1$ Where

$f(z)= \ln p$ if $n=p^m$ for some prime $p$ and some $m\in \Bbb N^+$

Or $f(z)=0$ otherwise.

---

I think that I need to use product formula $$\frac{1}{\zeta(z)}=\prod_p (1-1/p^z)$$ for $\Re z>1$

Please show me the solution more explicitly. Thank you.

Comment: It might help to note that $f'/f$ is the derivative of $\log f$.

Comment: What are its log$\zeta(z)$ and the derivative of log$\zeta(z)$? Please write explicitly.  Thank you:) @GerryMyerson

Comment: You have the product formula for zeta, and you know the log of a product is the sum of the logs, right? So I'm sure you can work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\;P:=$ the set of prime numbers in $\;\Bbb N =\;\{2,3,5,7,...\}\;$ , then

$$\zeta(s):=\prod_{p\in P}\frac1{1-p^{-s}}\implies\log\zeta(s)=-\sum_{p\in P}\log\left(1-\frac1{p^s}\right)\implies$$

$$\left(\log\zeta(s)\right)'=\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=-\sum_{p\in P}\frac{(\log p)p^{-s}}{1-p^{-s}}=-\sum_{p\in P}\log p\left(\frac1{1-p^{-s}}-1\right)=$$

$$=\sum\log p\sum_{n=1}^\infty p^{-ns}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Lambda (n)n^{-s}$$

The last equality following from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function) , with $\;\Lambda(n)=$ the Mangoldt Function.